# How to prove the Leibniz's rule for the product of a function and a generalized function ?.

Tags: distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

If $a\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and $T\in \mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$ How to prove $$D^\alpha(aT)=\sum_{\beta\leq\alpha}\binom{\alpha}{\beta}D^\beta aD^{\alpha-\beta}T$$

The following is my attempt.
$$
\begin{align}
D^\alpha(aT)(g)&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(aT)(D^\alpha g)\\
&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}T(aD^\alpha g)
\end{align}
$$
And
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\beta\leq\alpha}\binom{\alpha}{\beta}(D^\beta aD^{\alpha-\beta}T)(g)&=\sum_{\beta\leq\alpha}\binom{\alpha}{\beta}D^{\alpha-\beta}T(D^\beta a g)\\
&=\sum_{\beta\leq\alpha}\binom{\alpha}{\beta}T(D^{\alpha-\beta}(D^\beta a g))
\end{align}
$$
Why are the two formulas equal ?

Comment: See lemma 3.7 in [this document](http://web.math.ku.dk/~grubb/dist3.pdf)